# Setting the score on textview

Tags: android

I am trying to set the score in a game but it isn't doing anything at the moment.

I have declared a score variable:

```
    static int score = 0;
```

When an answer is shown in another textview as "Correct" I want the score to increment and show this in another textfield which will be for the score.

So far I have tried this:

```
  public void score(){
    check.getText();
if(check.equals("Correct")){
    score++;
    Score.setText(String.valueOf(score));

}
```

check is a Textfield which shows Correct or Incorrect. Score is another textfield. 
and then I put the method score() into an onclick, but this doesn't update the textfield.

I would appreciate any advice on this.

Thanks

Edit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
check.equals("Correct")
```

should be

```
check.getText().equals("Correct")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, at the moment it gives me an process closed error, but at least its doing something. Debugging it.

Comment: Appreciate any help Reno, cant figure out what the problem is. Keeps giving the process error no matter how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't heed the check.getText() method call that you have by itself. And you need to use this for your if statement

```
if(check.getText().toString().equals("correct))
```

getText returns the object type Editable which is not a String. If you are getting a force close please edit you question to include the stack trace from the LogCat output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have edited the above to include the stack trace. Thanks