# Android Process closed onClick

Tags: android

I am trying to make a score increment when an answer is shown as correct in a textfield. The code is as follows:

Variable is declared:

```
static int score = 0;
```

Method:

```
 public void score(){

if(check.getText().equals("Correct")){
    score++;
}
Score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}
```

The Score is a textfield and check is another textfield

Then this is called in onclick as score();

I appreciate any ideas on why this gets a process closed error when I am clicking the button.

Thanks.

Edit:

[image]

Comment: You already asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051102/setting-the-score-on-textview look back at this one a try the answer I put on it. And if you are going to ask about a force close it will make it far more likely that you get a response if you post the stack trace from your LogCat output.

Comment: First, usage of static variables in non-static context is wrong. Second, you must see what LogCat is showing, it helps a lot.

Comment: Downvoted for spamming same question.

Comment: Sorry just thought I wouldn't get an answer as the other question was about the if statement. I have tried using your answer but it still gives me an error. I have added the stack trace. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best advice I can give is set a break point at your if statement then use the debugger to see what is null.

Comment: Sorry made a little mistake in the id. ;)